# how do I permanently enlarge a pdf file

Tags: pdf, fontsize

I want to upload a pdf file to my REMARKABLE device as an enlarged item.
However after enlarging it [here](http://www.pdfdu.com/Download/121900191376.pdf?t=820)

the file still appears in the device as original in size. How do I enlarge it ?

**EDIT**
how do I make it larger in XeTeX ? I've tried this

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-]{111.pdf} 
\end{document}
```

But it gives an error.

```
Command Line:   bibtex.exe "obs"
Startup Folder: C:\Users\hynek0\Desktop\TH0dipl

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 20.6.29)
The top-level auxiliary file: obs.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file obs.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file obs.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file obs.aux
(There were 3 error messages)


Command Line:   xelatex.exe --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=-1 "obs.tex"
Startup Folder: C:\Users\hynek0\Desktop\TH0dipl

This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999992 (MiKTeX 20.6.29)
entering extended mode
(obs.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-06-18>
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/latex/base\size10.clo))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/latex/pdfpages\pdfpages.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/latex/base\ifthen.sty)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/latex/tools\calc.sty)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTex4\tex/latex/eso-pic\eso-pic.sty

LaTeX Warning: You have requested release `2020-10-01' of LaTeX,
               but only release `2020-02-02' is available.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \nointerlineskip \AddToHook 
                                       {shipout/background}{\put (0,\ESO@yof...
l.188 }
       
? 

! Emergency stop.
<argument> \nointerlineskip \AddToHook 
                                       {shipout/background}{\put (0,\ESO@yof...
l.188 }
       
No pages of output.

_____________________________________________________________________

 PDFTeXify Compilation Report (Pages: 0)

 Errors: 2   Warnings: 1   Bad Boxes: 0
_____________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: The file is reported to have a size of 864 x 1118 mm, so it is quite big (a normal A4 page is 210 x 297 mm). However, the file does not seem to be produced by LaTeX, so it is off topic for this site.

Comment: @Marijn PLease see my edit before closing.

Comment: Ok, the edit changes the question and now indeed it seems to be about LaTeX - however the error is not related to the pdf you are trying to include I think, it seems in your setup there is a general installation problem/version problem with LaTeX (and `pdfpages` in particular). To check this you can try to include a different pdf and see if you get the same error or not. To solve the issue you could try updating MikTeX (in user mode and also in admin mode) or maybe reinstall it altogether. I'll remove my close vote for the time being.

Comment: @Marijn I've totally disrupted my [MiKTEX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/627496/after-updating-miktex-i-get-the-following-error)